# Prof configuration (INCA tools)

Tags: automotive, xcp

I use the INCA tools for the first time. I would like to cset a prof config to flash binary file to my ECU. I tried to create the needed files. I have some question please.
1/ to convert the hex file into binary file i copied this from tuto

```
procedure convert
{
  [convert_bin]
   RUN_DLL ("CONVERT.DLL",convert,-h,-i,-q,-b,%1)
   case TRUE                 : $return TRUE
   default                   : $return FALSE 
  [convert_bin_END]
}
```

I would like to know what is the CONVERT.dll file, will it get generated automatically or should I create this file ?

2/ Can I flash directly a binary file to my ECU  ?
3/ who can correct my script I have several problems on ?
thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

> 1/ to convert the hex file into binary file i copied this from tuto
> I would like to know what is the CONVERT.dll file, will it get generated >automatically or should I create this file ?

CONVERT.dll is preset dll from INCA, no need to create this file, it's already available

> 2/ Can I flash directly a binary file to my ECU ?

yes, you can flash directly a binary file to your ECU

> 3/ who can correct my script I have several problems on ? thanks a lot :)

it need a lot of input and information from your hex file also